Port 80 and 443 is blocked to IIS
I would like to open port 80 and 443 to my IIS webserver. I have forwarded both ports to my PC running IIS.  I have proved that by running a port monitor that shows the ports are going to the correct PC.  I have tested port 80 remotely with Remote port tester
It says the ports are closed.  I have tested the ports from a different PC on my local LAN with this program   Free Port Scanner and it shows the ports are closed.
I have run netstat -aon | find /i "listening" |find "80"
and port 80 is not listening.  On IIS I do have the website stopped.
When I turn on the website and I try from a remote PC outside of my router to get to my domain with a web browser and I see on my port monitor port 80 is being forwarded to the IIS webserver PC.
I do have my firewall turned off.
I do have the firewall configured for Port 80
Profile All 
Enabled Yes 
Action Allow 
Override No 
Program Any 
Local Address Any 
Remote Address Any 
Protocol TCP 
Local port 80 
Remote port Any 
Authorized Users Any 
Authorized Computers Any 
Authorized Local Principals Any 
Local User Owner Any 
PolicyAppld None 
Application Package Any  

I have the same thing configured for port 443.
I do have Windows Defender turned off.
I do have my antivirus turned off.
How can I open port 80 and 443 in Windows 10 Pro IIS?

Please show what you've done in the firewall on the hosting computer.

Please use the formatting tools in the Editor to make arrange your question. Use paragraph breaks, in particular, to separate out the different sections of your post from each other. Also, it is not necessary to disable Defender and the Firewall. The correct way to do this is to leave these both turned ON, and then open the specific ports/protocols/applications you require. Finally, what research have you done regarding allowing traffic over ports 80 and 443 to IIS on a Windows 10 computer?

Thank you for the reply...  I know I can, and eventually will, leave the windows firewall on.  Out of desperation I have turned it off for testing to make sure I don't have a configuration problem.  I don't use Windows Defender.  I have installed Bitdefender Firewall and it's turned off.  I think I have the question formatted easier to read now.  I have been doing research on this for two days now.

is it possible your internet provider blocks those ports - some do

When I am on a remote site and I try to go to my domain, my router port monitor shows me the port forwarding on port 80 going to my server.  So it's getting through to my router. So it's being blocked on my Win 10 IIS server.

@JaromandaX I wasn't going to worry about the outside network issue until the internal issue was resolved. One may fix the others.

Given that you have the firewall turned off, I will also assume that you have any other firewall turned off. Port 443 and port 80 should therefor be open. If its not working in IIS,  it could be that it is actually working in IIS, but that IIS itself now blocks it due to a misconfiguration, or that another program uses ports 80 and 443. I would download paping, and from the IIS machine itself, do a paping localhost -p 443, keep it running and tweak stuff until you see green text. Do the same for port 80. Optionally use a different port and test that. You can always change the NATrule.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/paping/
